# Background color discrepancy

Tags: android, android-theme

On a part of my layout I need to force the background to the same color of the default background color of the light theme (actually `Theme.AppCompat.Light`).

So I added this attribute : `android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"`.

But this background color is lighter than the default I have in the rest of my app.

From the android `themes.xml`, in the holo light theme, `?android:attr/colorBackground` targets `@android:background_holo_light` which is equals to `#f3f3f3`. But the default background color is more something like `#eeeeee`, I really wonder where this color came from ?

The problem occurs on Kitkat, I don't have color discrepancy under Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the answer, for hardware accelerated devices, `android:attr/windowBackground` points to a gradient, not a plain color like I expected.

So when I use `android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"` for on of my view, depending to where it is located in the screen height, we can see a color discrepancy.

The solution is to override `windowBackground` with `colorBackground` in the theme :

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
```